# Extending a rails model with concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I've got this file in `models/extensions/url.rb`:

```
module Extensions
  module Url
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_url(attribute)
      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods
    end
  end
end
```

Then I might have a model that looks like:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Extensions::Url

  acts_as_url :title

  field :title, :type => String
end
```

Where in the extensions module can I make it so that each instance has a method / accessor called `url` so that I can access the `:title` field (passed as the attribute parameter) and be able to do:

```
post = Post.find(params[:id])
puts post.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define your `url` method inside of your `Url` module and outside of your `ClassMethods` module. Anything defined there will be added as an instance method.

You can put it in your `InstanceMethods` module, but Rails recently updated `ActiveSupport::Concern` to treat anything outside of the `ClassMethods` module as an instance method.

Comment: Ok cool, good to know about the location of instance methods - I guess my question is more about how to access the :title field dynamically (not directly reference the title, but rather reference the variable that references the field).

Comment: If you set it as an attribute of the `Post` object, you could just use `self.title` in your `url` method.

Comment: My url method is on the class and the attribute is reference dynamically. So for one class it might need to reference `self.title` but for another it might be `self.other_field`.